# How to update array to firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new in this field. I see there are many ways on the internet and most of them is about the old version of Firebase, like using `push()`, `update()`, `save()`. So, I really don't know how to update it. I tried that like this:

```
function writeNewEvent(eObj) {
          // A post entry.
            var userObj = authObj.$getAuth();

            // Get a key for a new Post.
            var newEventKey = ref.child('events').child(userObj.uid).push().key;

            // Write the new post's data simultaneously in the posts list and the user's post list.
            var updates = {};
            updates['/events/' + userObj.uid+ '/' + newEventKey] = userObj;

            return ref.update(updates);
        }
```

But the error is:

```
angular.js:13920 Error: Firebase.update failed: First argument  contains an invalid key ($d) in property 'events.LRnkjDgEu1QtuvUTazTwyms4U063.-KW56c87MThrK0PZp-XH.f'.  Keys must be non-empty strings and can't contain ".", "#", "$", "/", "[", or "]"
```

Could you tell me if my method is correct? And how to implement this function.

Comment: *There are many ways on the internet* Yes, but there is one way in the Firebase documentation. Try reading that first. For instance, `push` will not return an object containing the `key` as you apparently hope. It returns a **promise**, and the value of the promise of the promise has a `key` field you can use. All of this is well explained in the docs; as usual, you just have to read it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have an ID so you don't need to use push(), just set() at the id like:

```
// assuming your input looks somthing like:
let eObj = {
  "uuid": "98765-8765-1234567890-7890",
  "some-data": "stuff",
  "other-data": "other stuff",
  "numeric-data": 12345
}

function writeNewEventUsingObjUuid(eObj) {
  // A post entry.
  var userObj = authObj.$getAuth();

  return ref.child('events').child(userObj.uid).set(eObj).then(function () {
    console.log('Event added with ID: ' + userObj.uid);
  }).catch(function (e) {
    console.log('Error adding event: ' + e.message);
  });
}
```

If you really want to use push(), firebase will assign you an ID. Note that an empty push() like you had returns a thenable reference. The work is still done asynchronously event though you get an ID upfront.